# How to add an additional Conv2DTranspose layer to get 56x56 mask

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

```
def build_fpn_mask_graph(rois, feature_maps, image_meta,
                         pool_size, num_classes, train_bn=True):
    """Builds the computation graph of the mask head of Feature Pyramid Network.

    rois: [batch, num_rois, (y1, x1, y2, x2)] Proposal boxes in normalized
          coordinates.
    feature_maps: List of feature maps from different layers of the pyramid,
                  [P2, P3, P4, P5]. Each has a different resolution.
    image_meta: [batch, (meta data)] Image details. See compose_image_meta()
    pool_size: The width of the square feature map generated from ROI Pooling.
    num_classes: number of classes, which determines the depth of the results
    train_bn: Boolean. Train or freeze Batch Norm layers

    Returns: Masks [batch, num_rois, MASK_POOL_SIZE, MASK_POOL_SIZE, NUM_CLASSES]
    """
    # ROI Pooling
    # Shape: [batch, num_rois, MASK_POOL_SIZE, MASK_POOL_SIZE, channels]
    x = PyramidROIAlign([pool_size, pool_size],
                        name="roi_align_mask")([rois, image_meta] + feature_maps)

    # Conv layers
    x = KL.TimeDistributed(KL.Conv2D(256, (3, 3), padding="same"),
                           name="mrcnn_mask_conv1")(x)
    x = KL.TimeDistributed(BatchNorm(),
                           name='mrcnn_mask_bn1')(x, training=train_bn)
    x = KL.Activation('relu')(x)

    x = KL.TimeDistributed(KL.Conv2D(256, (3, 3), padding="same"),
                           name="mrcnn_mask_conv2")(x)
    x = KL.TimeDistributed(BatchNorm(),
                           name='mrcnn_mask_bn2')(x, training=train_bn)
    x = KL.Activation('relu')(x)

    x = KL.TimeDistributed(KL.Conv2D(256, (3, 3), padding="same"),
                           name="mrcnn_mask_conv3")(x)
    x = KL.TimeDistributed(BatchNorm(),
                           name='mrcnn_mask_bn3')(x, training=train_bn)
    x = KL.Activation('relu')(x)

    x = KL.TimeDistributed(KL.Conv2D(256, (3, 3), padding="same"),
                           name="mrcnn_mask_conv4")(x)
    x = KL.TimeDistributed(BatchNorm(),
                           name='mrcnn_mask_bn4')(x, training=train_bn)
    x = KL.Activation('relu')(x)

    x = KL.TimeDistributed(KL.Conv2DTranspose(256, (2, 2), strides=2, activation="relu"),
                           name="mrcnn_mask_deconv")(x)
    x = KL.TimeDistributed(KL.Conv2D(num_classes, (1, 1), strides=1, activation="sigmoid"),
                           name="mrcnn_mask")(x)
    return x
```

Above code, I have got from matterport mask rcnn. I need to add an additional  Conv2DTranspose layer to get a 56x56 mask. How can I do that? I don't know anything about TensorFlow. I think above code is designed for 28x28 mask. But I need to get 56x56 resolution mask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add another

```
 x = KL.TimeDistributed(KL.Conv2DTranspose(256, (2, 2), strides=2, activation="relu"),
                           name="mrcnn_mask_deconv")(x)
```

before the final layer with the `sigmoid` activation.

It does not matter if you know TensorFlow or PyTorch. Think of the `TransposedConvolution()` as the opposite of `Convolution()`.

When applying on an image of 4x4 a `convolution` with kernel (2,2) with strides = 2, we obtain a final output feature map of dimension 2x2. Exactly the opposite when it comes to `TransposedConvolution`; a transposed convolution with a kernel of (2,2) and a stride of 2 will double the size of the output image. hence transforming an input image of dimension 2x2 to an output one of 4x4.